# rewrite aspx to php

Tags: .htaccess

I have moved an .aspx website to php and I am having problems with the 301 redirects.

The old url is: c-2-rates.aspx
The new url is: rates.php

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect 301 /c-2-rates.aspx http://YouDomain.com/rates.php
```

Comment: Are you on a Linux server? htaccess works on a Linux server.  I'm thinking you're on a Windows server since you asked about ASP.NET - this means htaccess is not an option.